# Finding kustomize version shipped with kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

I usually use the kustomize supplied with kubectl. I'm wondering if there is a way to find the kustomize version that is shipped with kubectl ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For earlier version of kubectl, there was no such way of doing it and there was an issue related to it: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1424

But it has been fixed recently and it seems starting from `1.24` we are able to get the version by just doing `kubectl version`:

```
❯ ./kubectl version --short --client
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.24.8
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
```

For the older clients, you can find that it is documented in the kustomize's README here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize#kubectl-integration

| Kubectl version | Kustomize version |
| --- | --- |
| < v1.14 | n/a |
| v1.14-v1.20 | v2.0.3 |
| v1.21 | v4.0.5 |
| v1.22 | v4.2.0 |